# Salesforce REST API get a list of updated records

Tags: api, rest, salesforce

I want to have a list of records under accounts object from a particular time to a particular time

say for example this my api query:
https://ax1.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/updated/?start=2015-06-30T06%3A49%3A00%2B00%3A00&end=2015-06-30T16%3A30%3A26%2B00%3A00

In my salesforce the time I have chosen is Indian Time which is UTC + 5:30

I created an account at 16:45 pm on 30th June in Indian time(as per salesforce this time is shown in the created by field of the account)

but for the above query in which I have chosen the start time and end time is 06:49 AM and 16:30 PM respectively

I got the record id which I have added at 16 45 pm Indian time but it shouldn't come in the response

The following is the response:
"ids": [
        "0019000001QeOINAA3"
    ],
    "latestDateCovered": "2015-06-30T09:00:00.000+0000"
}

Also the latestDateCovered it says 09 AM only

I don't understand this system

Could somebody help me on how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API REST API will be working with UTC DateTime values.

So you searched for records between:

- 2015-06-30 06:49:00 UTC
- 2015-06-30 16:30:26 UTC

Which I make to be:

- 2015-06-30 12:19:00 IST
- 2015-06-30 22:00:26 IST

So it would make sense that a record created at 16:45 pm on the 30th of June IST would appear in the results.

Try checking the `SystemModStamp` and `LastModifiedDate` fields in the API for the record in question, as the values will also be in UTC there.

Comment: Yeah thank you so much for you reply.Is there any way by which we can know through api which time is being followed in Salesforce. For example,If I change my time in salesforce account to IST,can the same be identified in REST api

Comment: also one more question:                                                                               in the field LastModifiedDate of REST api response the response is as follows:                                                                                                             latestDateCovered": "2015-06-30T09:00:00.000+0000"  what does that + symbol in the above signify,It should have actually change the time right,but I am getting the UTC time only and not IST time Please help

Comment: @user1918861 You can get the [User.TimeZoneSidKey](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) via the API. The [Timezone](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_timezone.htm) Apex class may also be useful for the UTC offset. The "+0000" is indicating the UTC offset. In this case no offset.

Comment: I am using java,I am not using apex also rest api and not soap so I cannot use that. When I changed my salesforce timings to ist,I should get +0530 instead of +0000 right? but I am getting only +0000? why should it be it like that?

Comment: @user1918861 The API will **always** return DateTimes at UTC (+0000). You can use the REST API to run a SOQL query and retrieve the timezone information. Maybe ask a new question if you want to figure out how to do that. The http://salesforce.stackexchange.com is a great place for Salesforce specific questions.

Comment: can you answer the following question in the given link:                                      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272762/updating-and-deleting-records-in-salesforce-using-rest-api